# Unable to get Processor Speed in Device

Tags: c++, windows, windows-ce, winapi

Hi i am using QueryperformanceFrequency to get the No of cycle i.e processor speed.
But it is showing me the wrong value. It is written in the specicfication is the Processor is about 400MHz, but what we are getting through code is something 16MHz.

Please porvide any pointer :

The code for Wince device is:

```
LARGE_INTEGER FrequnecyCounter;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&FrequnecyCounter);

CString temp;

temp.Format(L"%lld",FrequnecyCounter.QuadPart)`AfxMessageBox(temp);
```

Thanks,

Mukesh

Answer (score 2):

QueryPerformanceFrequency returns frequency of the counter peripheral not of the processor. These peripheral typically runs at the original Crystal clock frequency. 16Mhz should be good enough resolution for you to measure fine grain intervals.

Comment: But if i am applying the same thing for desktop, its giving me the exact tick count  like 2.9 GHZ, same as Processor speed, then why not for the wince device...??

Comment: @mukesh: it can be the same as the CPU clock speed or it can be some other value - there is no requirement for the performance counter clock to be the same as the CPU clock. If you want the CPU clock speed then use an appropriate API to get it.

Comment: @mukesh As PauL R said this can be same as CPU clock speed. Looking at the figures you have quoted, I feel you are using some embedded SOC  look at documentation to figure out which counter is being used for implementing this API. In such system the high frequency CPU clock will be cut whenever CPU is idle for more then certain threshold to save power, so it makes sense to implement Performance Counters using a clock which remains available through out.  If you take any smartphone platform then quite often you will see value of 32KHZ reported as performance counter frequency.

Answer (score 1):

QPF doesn't return the CPU clock speed. It returns the frequency of *a* high performance timer. On a few systems, it might actually measure CPU cycles. On other systems, it might use s a separate timer running at the same frequency. (but which is unaffected by things like SpeedStep which can change the clock speed of the CPU). Often, it uses a separate timer entirely, one which may not even be on the CPU itself, but may be part of the motherboard.

QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency only promise that they use *the best* timer available on the system. They make no promises about what that timer might be.